# capture the details of 'dynamic_link_app_open' log event in firebase nodejs cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-analytics

I am using the firebase cloud function in nodejs to intercept the 'dynamic_link_app_open' log event which is generated on-click of dynamic link in the app. I don't see the required details being passed in the event param apart from the defaults values.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const https = require('https')
const options = {
    hostname: ‘*****.com',
    path: ‘/********’,
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
}

const data = ‘{“*”*************}}’

exports.sendDynamicLinkAppOpen = functions.region("asia-south1").analytics.event('dynamic_link_app_open').onLog(event => {
    console.debug('dynamic_link_app_open');
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
        console.log('param: ')
        console.log(event.params)
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            console.log('stdout.write')
            process.stdout.write(d)
        })
    })

    req.on('error', (error) => {
        console.error(error)
    })

    req.write(data)
    req.end()
    return;
  });
```

Params being returned:
{
debug_event: 1,
dynamic_link_accept_time: 435465676755,
dynamic_link_link_id: 'temp_link_id',
firebase_conversion: 1,
firebase_event_origin: 'fdl',
firebase_screen_class: 'MainActivity',
firebase_screen_id: 134567,
medium: 'dynamic_link',
source: 'firebase'
}

Comment: Hello, can you please include the node.js cloud function code ?

Comment: @marian.vladoi i have updated the question with code. And nodejs is new to me so please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

Comment: I checked your code, however I do not see any issues. You can also use Google Analytics in your app to track the performance of your [Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/analytics). ```dynamic_link_app_open``` is automatically logged when you open a short or long Dynamic Link in your app.

Comment: @marian.vladoi i have a requirement of posting the analytic details to an external api

Comment: I understand, however I do not see any issues whith your code